# Add custom calculated shipping to the total on checkout in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I want to add custom calculated shipping value (based on the origin of the shipment of the book) to the total amount of the order. I can now calculate the shipping value based on the order ID in my custom module....

I want to be able to add this value to the order total on checkout, is that possible?
I have tried shipment rules, but it is not satisfactory as it only allows me to add a value to the line items in the order and not to total. How can I hook to the checkout process and add this amount to the total? Maybe I can add it as custom line items on checkout?

Also, since it is a custom shipment method with customs shipment companies, do I need to use any of the shipment modules in the first place ( I neither use flat service or any of the commerce shipment modules) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try API of respective commerce/ubercart module. They must offer some API which allows you to modify the check out page